# Counting the subgroups of order $6$ in a group of order $42$ which has a subgroup of order $6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

> Let be $G$ a group of order $42$. Suppose $G$ has a subgroup of order $6$. Compute the number of conjugates of this subgroup in $G$.

This is what I thought:

Let be $H$ the subgroup of order $6$ and $K$ the only one $7$-subgroup of Sylow.

If $G$ is abelian, then there is an only one conjugate of $H$ in $G$. If $G$ is non abelian, we proceed as follow:

Acting $K$ on $H$ by conjugation,

$$|H| \equiv |N_G(H) \cap K| \ \text{mod} \ 7$$

by the theorem $4.1$ on page $18$ of [this lecture notes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/gpaction.pdf), therefore $|N_G(H) \cap K| = 6$. On the one hand, the number of conjugates of $H$ with respect to $K$ is $\frac{|G|}{|N_G(H) \cap K|} = \frac{42}{6} = 7$. By the other hand, $hHh^{-1} = H$ for every $h \in H$, but $eHe^{-1}$ is a conjugate of $H$ with respect to $e \in K$, then $hHh^{-1} = eHe^{-1}$ for every $h \in H$, therefore $H$ has exactly $7$ conjugates in $G$. $\square$

I don't sure about this argument, because I stated "the number of conjugates of $H$ with respect to $K$ is $\frac{|G|}{|N_G(H) \cap K|}$". I know that it's true that the number of conjugates of $H$ in $G$ is $\frac{|G|}{|N_G(H)|}$, but I don't sure if what I stated it's true, I couldn't realize what action group I need to define to ensure that my statement it's true. I would like to know if what I do is correct and if it is how ensure that the number of conjugates of $H$ with respect to $K$ is $\frac{|G|}{|N_G(H) \cap K|}$. If this is not correct, I would like a hint in order to compute the number of conjugates of $H$ in $G$.

Comment: Your answer is correct: if $G$ is nonabelian, then there are exactly $7$ cyclic subgroups of order $6$, and they are all conjugate.  (There are actually three isomorphism classes of groups with this property, but they all have $7$ cyclic subgroups of order $6$)

Comment: @DerekHolt, do you know what is the homomorphism which ensure my statement of that "the number of conjugates of $H$ with respect to $K$ is $\frac{|G|}{|N_G(H) \cap K|}$"?

Comment: That's not correct, because $|N_K(H)|=1$. The number of conjugates of $H$ is $|G/N_G(H)|$, but $N_K(H)=1$, so $N_G(H)= H$ has order $6$.

Comment: Are you considering $N_K(H) = N_G(H) \cap K$, right? Why  $|N_K(H)| = 1$? I thought $N_K(H)$ would have $6$ elements and how exactly did you conclude that $N_G(H) = H$?

Comment: Wait a moment, I think that I understood why $N_G(H) = H$. I will post my explanation soon

Comment: I know that $N_G(H)$ is the largest subgroup of $G$ such that $H \trianglelefteq N_G(H)$ and $H \trianglelefteq G \iff N_G(H) = G$ by the definition of the normalizer of $H$ in $G$. If $G$ is non abelian, then $H$ is not normal in $G$, otherwise, $G = H \times K$, which is an absurd since $H \times K$ is a product of two abelian groups, then $N_G(H) \neq G$, but $H \leq N_G(H)$ and $N_G(H) \leq G$, then $|H|$ divides $|N_G(H)|$ and $|N_G(H)|$ divides the order of $|G|$, therefore $|N_G(H)| = 6$ since $N_G(H) \neq G$. Thus, $N_G(H) = H$, because $|N_G(H)| = 6$, $|H| = 6$ and $H \leq N_G(H)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was proved on the comments that if $G$ is non abelian and $H \leq G$ such that $|H| = 6$, then $N_G(H) = H$. Thus, the number of conjugates of $H$ is $[G : N_G(H)] = \frac{|G|}{|N_G(H)|} = \frac{42}{6} = 7$.